# Logback: Nesting markers within message field

Tags: java, json, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm using Logback with logstash-logback-encoder to allow JSON logging and have a requirement to include Marker content within the message field.

Log statement with marker:

```
log.error(append("errorCode", errorInfo.getErrorCode())
        .and(append("errorMessage", errorInfo.getErrorMessage())),
        "bla",
        ex);
```

Output:

```
{
    "@timestamp":"2017-11-20T13:34:49.147+00:00",
    "severity":"ERROR",
    "threadID":"main",
    "logger":"com.mycompany.MyClass",
    "message": {
        "errorCode":"XYZ-0001",
        "errorMessage":"Some Exception occured",
        "stack_trace":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Some Text\r\n\ <rest of stacktrace>"
    }
}
```

This is my appender config:

```
<appender name="STDOUT_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "severity": "%level",
                    "threadID": "%thread",
                    "logger": "%logger{40}"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            <nestedField>
                <fieldName>message</fieldName>
                <providers>
                    <logstashMarkers />
                    <stackTrace />
                </providers>
            </nestedField>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The problem I'm facing now is that log statements without markers don't populate the message field anymore:

```
log.info("some info message");
```

yields an empty message field:

```
{"@timestamp":"2017-11-20T13:45:12.146+00:00","severity":"INFO","threadID":"main","logger":"s.s.a.AuthorizationFacadeRepository","message":{}}
```

If I include `"message": "%message"` in the pattern or in the nestedField I get either two nested message elements or two message elements in the first level of the JSON.

So how can I include markers as nested object in the message field in the right way?

Comment: What is stopping you from using the default net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder? The above should work then.